# read scientific number missing e delimiters in matlab

Tags: string, matlab, format

Could someone help in reading the following data format in matlab?

GRID     7              -.0091  .19725  .067776

GRID     8              .0011   .19725  .067776

GRID     9              -.004   .19725  .027776

GRID*    4998                           .086001         .206

- 7.5-4

GRID*    4999                           .086001          0.

- 7.5-4

GRID*    5000                           .151999         .206

- 7.5-4

GRID*    5001                            0.             1.-6

- 7.5-4

GRID*    5002                           .151999          0.

- 7.5-4

GRID*    5003                            0.             .206001

- 7.5-4

GRID     1000016        -.0082  .019249 .127546

the problem is the numbers in the format like 7.5-4 that should have formatted as 7.5e-4 and that matlab doesnot recognized as floating point delimiters %f

for the moment I am using the folowing command
line=textscan(firstLine,'%s %u %u %f %f')

that is not getting the strange scientific format

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Use the format `%f%f` which reads in mantissa and exponent individually:

```
[a]=textscan('7.5-4','%f%f')
a{1}.*10.^a{2}
```